# How to use JavaScript inside {{}} AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I know that {{}} can interpret a expression but when I try to use javascript in it, it does not work like `{{"a/b/c/d/".split('/').filter(function(n){return n}).reverse()[0]}}`

I need to use this to get slug value from url.

Please suggest how to achieve this with angularjs, the source of the url is from external feed, hence I have very limited control on this.

Comment: nice question...same what i required.

Comment: You better embed it in model's function, like `getSlug()` and use it like `{{ item.getSlug() }}`. This is more consistent way

Comment: You can't and you shouldn't. See [Angular Expressions vs. JS Expressions](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression), or at least you can't expect any arbitrary javascript to just work. *... If, on the other hand, you do want to run arbitrary JavaScript code, you should make it a controller method and call the method. If you want to eval() an angular expression from JavaScript, use the $eval() method.*

Comment: Not really related to the question, but if you're trying to extract the last segment of your url you can just use `url.split('/').pop()` or `url.substr(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1)`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Full JS is not supported, and even it were, it would be a bad practice.

I recommend you to put this at least on a scope function in your controller.
Even better would be to put it in a service or in a filter, so if you want to reuse it later for other purposes you can:

```
$scope.getSlug = function( str ) {
  return str.split( "/" ).filter(function( n ) {
    return n;
  }).reverse()[ 0 ];
};
```

And then, in your template:

```
{{ getSlug( "a/b/c/d/" ) }}
{{ getSlug( myModelProperty ) }}
```

Also, it's valid to read the [Angular docs about expressions](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression).

Comment: but how would i use this in {{}} on html??

Comment: Bravo.. exactly what i was looking for.. muchas gracias.. amigo :D

Comment: It's the original purpose of filter. Usually it fits best as it's not tied to certain controller.

Answer (score 5):

You shouldn't be using templating like that - so Angular doesn't support it. Either create a function in the scope:

```
$scope.getSlug = function (input) {
    return input.split('/').filter(function(n){return n}).reverse()[0];
}
```

Or create a filter that does what you want to acheive:

```
angular.module('myModule').filter('myFilter', function () {

    return function (input) {
         if (!input) return input;

         return input.split('/').filter(function(n){return n}).reverse()[0];
    };
});
```

And use it like this:

```
<div>{{"a/b/c/d" | myFilter}}</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

`{{}}` tell Angular that in your view, you have an Expression to interpolate. Angular expressions do not support all of JavaScript.  For documentation [check here](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression).

If you need all of JavaScript.  It is better to wrap the logic in a controller function.

Excerpt from docs:

> It might be tempting to think of Angular view expressions as
>   JavaScript expressions, but that is not entirely correct, since
>   Angular does not use a JavaScript eval() to evaluate expressions. You
>   can think of Angular expressions as JavaScript expressions with
>   following differences:
>
> **Attribute Evaluation:** evaluation of all properties are against the
>   scope doing the evaluation, unlike in JavaScript where the expressions
>   are evaluated against the global window.
>
> **Forgiving:** expression evaluation is forgiving to undefined and null,
>   unlike in JavaScript, where trying to evaluate undefined properties
>   can generate ReferenceError or TypeError.
>
> **No Control Flow Statements:** you cannot do any of the following in
>   angular expression: conditionals, loops, or throw.