# Use builtin Javascript Functions in angular template

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I am trying to run an `eval` in my angular template like so:

```html
<div *ngFor="...">
  <div *ngIf="eval('...')"></div>
</div>
```

You get the idea.

But I get the following error:

```
error TS2339: Property 'eval' does not exist on type 'CreateComponent'.
```

Obviously angular thinks that eval is a property of the component.
How do I fix this?

Don't tell me eval is evil. I know that and my use case is absolutely safe.
I can't just move the logic from the expression into a function on the controller.

Comment: Are you sure with what you are doing? https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/94017/what-are-the-security-issues-with-eval-in-javascript

Comment: Yes. I just use it something like `eval("variableName" + i)` in the loop

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20679412/5196619

Comment: eval is evil in javascript https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval

Comment: Yes, I already mentioned that my use case is safe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason this doesn't work is because Angular looks for a function called `eval` in your class and it can't find it, you can easily solve this by adding that function to your class:

```js
eval(evaluation: string) {
     return eval(evaluation)
}
```

```html
<div *ngFor="...">
  <div *ngIf="eval('...')"></div>
</div>
```

I'll also mention that it's a bad idea to use functions in your template, as every time change detection happens Angular evaluates the function and it will reduce the performance on your app.

BTW, there's no reason not to use your component for this, and there's no limiatations really. If you need to pass a reference, you can just pass it as a parameter:

```js
eval(string, ref) {
  return eval(string + ref)
}
```

```html
<div *ngFor="...">
      <div *ngIf="eval('...', myRef)"></div>
      <div #myRef></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice Answer, but if i try something like `eval('myReference' + i + '.close()')` and i use a function it gives an error because it looks for `myReference1` (or any other number) in the .ts file instead of the .html file

Comment: Almost anything you can do in the template you can do in the component as well, share full code example or stackblitz if you want specific help.

Comment: I have found a way of not using references for now... That works but I think at some other point this will happen.

Answer (score 1):

You can declare in your component

```
export class AppComponent  {
  eval = eval
}
```

Now you can simply use the function in your HTML

[See Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-mstr7o?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: I did this, but the problem is that now the expression goes into the controller. That can't work in my use case, ie. I am using it to refer to a #reference like `eval("#ref" + index)`.

Comment: Is this angular or angularjs?

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the above answers, We can create a custom pipe with the below logic (Which was suggested by **Yair Cohen**).

```js
eval(evaluation: string) {
 return eval(evaluation)
}
```

By using our own custom pipe one can reuse the same logic throughout the application on a need basis. Correct me if in case of any modification needed.